# Produce php variable while looping through query and in certain order

Tags: php

I have a while fetch_assoc that produces and xml file for me. It works fine but now i need to add another variable to it.

Here is the working query

```
$sql3 = "SELECT name, class FROM tbl_user_tmp where user = '$user' order by name";

if(!$result3 = $mysqli->query($sql3)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $mysqli->error . ']');
}

while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){

if(!isset($previousRow2) || !isset($previousRow2["category"]) || $previousRow2["category"] != $row2["category"])
{
    $xml2 .= "\r\n";
    $xml2 .= "<category title=\"" . $row2["category"] . "\" />\r\n";
}
$xml2 .= "    <item drawable=\"";

$xml2 .= $row2["name"];

$xml2 .= "\" />";
$xml2 .= "\r\n";


$previousRow2 = $row2;
}
```

Now, what i need to do is take a array, and based on it,order what titles get done first.

This is how the array looks
$cat_order[]
Games,Apps,Google,Misc,System

Comment: It's a bit messy. Can you provide the current result and the result you want?

Comment: Well i stumbled across the order by FIELD method and that seems like what i need. The values from $cat_order will always match what the query should be. So would breaking the array into separate variables and inserting each one into the query work? only problem is the amount of variables will vary. not sure how to do it

Comment: Ok, so you want to handle the rows according to `cat_order`?
First all games, then all apps etc..? Also.. how is `sql3` related? You are not selecting anything related to `category` as far as I can see. What is `result2`?

Comment: yes. cat_order is to tell which category title gets done first. and i just figured out order by FIELD is column (duh). if i could order by row that would be what i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can order this in the query:

```
<?php


//Dynamic solution, build the SQL with a loop:
$cat_order = array("Games", "Apps", "Google");
$caseStr = "";
foreach($cat_order as $index => $value)
  $caseStr .= sprintf("WHEN '%s' THEN %d ", $value, $index+1);


$sql3 = "
  SELECT name, class 
  FROM tbl_user_tmp where user = '$user' 
  ORDER BY CASE name" . $caseStr . " END";
?>
```

Comment: Sorry but it has to be dynamic.

Comment: I've modified the solution. You get the drill.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to ask then answer but here is how i did it

```
    $cat_name = $_POST['cat'];

foreach($cat_name as $k=>$val)
{
    $cat_order[] = $val;
}


debug_to_console($cat_order);

$sql2 = "SELECT distinct category, name FROM tbl_user_tmp where user = '$user' and category is not null and category <> '' order by field (category,";


$size = count($cat_name);
foreach($cat_name as $k=>$val)
{
    $sql2 .= "'$val'";
    if($size > $k+1) $sql2 .=',';
}


$sql2 .= ")";

debug_to_console($sql2);
```